# nibabel.filebasedimages.ImageFileError for large label files

Tags: nibabel

I am getting the following error when loading a large labeled NIFTI file of size 14.4 MB.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miran045/reine097/projects2/lab2im/lab2im/dcan/reproduce_load_error.py", line 7, in <module>
    img = nib.load(file_path)
  File "/home/miran045/reine097/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nibabel/loadsave.py", line 55, in load
    raise ImageFileError(f'Cannot work out file type of "{filename}"')
nibabel.filebasedimages.ImageFileError: Cannot work out file type of "/home/feczk001/shared/data/nnUNet/nnUNet_raw_data_base/nnUNet_raw_data/Task509_Paper/labelsTr1/1mo_sub-375518.nii.gz"
```

Here is the code:

```
import nibabel as nib

print(nib.__version__)

file_path = '/home/feczk001/shared/data/nnUNet/nnUNet_raw_data_base/nnUNet_raw_data/Task509_Paper/labelsTr1/1mo_sub' \
            '-375518.nii.gz'
img = nib.load(file_path)
print(img.shape)
```

This does not happen when I try to open such files of smaller size (on the order of KB).  I can open this file in FreeSurfer FreeView without error and it looks fine.  This is happening with version 3.2.1 of NiBabel.

Answer (score 0):

The file is probably not actually zipped, despite the GZ file extension.  Try gzipping it.